# comparing results from 1 table with multiple variables, finding comonalities

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

thanks in advance. I'm finding it hard to put this into words. I have 1 table called conversation_users. it contains columns: id, user_id, & conversation_id.

I need to take a list of user ids, lets say 4...could be 9, and find the conversation_id they all have in common but does not contain any other user ids.

Can this be done in 1 query? if not, can someone point me in the right direction?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" query.  You can construct it for a specific set of users as:

```
select cu.conversation_id
from conversation_users cu
group by cu.conversation_id
having sum(cu.user = x) > 0 and
       sum(cu.user = y) > 0 and
       sum(cu.user = z) > 0 and
       sum(cu.user not in (x, y, z)) = 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause (except the last) checks that a given user is in the conversation.  The last checks that no other users are in it.

If you store the users you care about in a temporary table or string (in the horrible comma-separated format), you can still do this:

```
select cu.conversation_id
from conversation_users cu
group by cu.conversation_id
having count(distinct (case when find_in_set(cu.user, @USERLIST) > 0 then cu.user end)) = 
           1 + length(@USERLIST) - length(replace(@USERLIST, ',', '') and
       count(distinct cu.user_id) = 1 + length(@USERLIST) - length(replace(@USERLIST, ',', '')
```

What this says is that the number of matching users in the list is equal to the size of the list, and the total number of matching users is the size of the list.  These two conditions say that all members of the list are in the conversation.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. For laravel use this link for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976241/implementing-group-by-and-having-in-laravel-using-eloquent