# Like and group by in Laravel 4.2

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I use `group by` with a count function in LARAVEL 4.2. When I tried to use `LIKE` in the same query, it gave me the error `Invalid use of group function`, as we can't use `like` with `group by`. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use **Mysql aggregate function with** **`group`** & **`like`** both together you have to use `having` instead of `like`.

Check here [MySQL :: MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual :: 12.16.3 MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

and here: [A similar SO question answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976241/implementing-group-by-and-having-in-laravel-using-eloquent/17099838#17099838)

Comment: I can use like and group by together but when you use an aggregate function with group by then MySQL throws an error.

Comment: @KhurramSatti yes you are right my mistake, changed answer.