# Apply Where Clause of Left Join when common results are fetched - Laravel 5.1

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

my database structure is as follows:

> Table: **users**

```
id | username | email | password | status
```

> Table: **articles**

```
id | user_id(fk) | title | other | status
```

> Table: **analytics**

```
id | user_id | article_id(fk) | session | revenue | country_code
```

Now I want all the articles, but also I want the data from **analytics** table. I want all the rows GROUP BY Article ID from analytics whose Total SUM of Session is greater than 200.

What I performed is as follows:

```
$articles = Article::selectRaw('articles.*, sum(analytics.revenue) as sum, IF(Sum(analytics.sessions) >= 200, Sum(analytics.sessions), 0)  AS sum_sessions
                ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'articles.user_id')
                ->leftJoin('analytics', function ($join) {
                    $join->on('analytics.article_id', '=', 'articles.id')
                        ->on('analytics.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                        ->where('users.status','!=', '3')
                        ->where('analytics.country_code','=', 'US');
                })
                ->where('articles.status', 4)
                ->groupBy('articles.id')
                ->orderBy('articles.created_at', 'DESC')
                ->get();
```

But after putting the following condition in LEFT JOIN

```
->on('analytics.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
->where('users.status','!=', '3')
->where('analytics.country_code','=', 'US');
```

results are not being shown as it should be.

So what I want to do is I want to apply where condition to the LEFT JOIN only when common results appears from both the table, not when results from Left Tables are only shown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing group\_by and having in Laravel using Eloquent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976241/implementing-group-by-and-having-in-laravel-using-eloquent)

Comment: Hi, that question is totally different, Please read at least once my full description, Thank you for your efforts